# Grove I2C display not working on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, i2c

I only have my RPi 3B and a I²C display, I don't own any GrovePi hat and I want to show some text to the said display. Is there a way to make it work?

- [My display](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-16x2_LCD_Series/#resources).
- `i2cdetect -y 1` shows this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2mUr.jpg), meaning the RPi is detecting the I²C display and it should work. But nothing seemed to be showing on the display, except for the full block on the first row.
- I've tried literally everything on the internet, some library worked (as in throwing no errors) but the display still stays the same, full block on the first row.
- I've installed python3, smbus, smbus2 and i2c-tools. I've changed the address to `3e`.
- My most recent **.py* file. It does write 'LCD printing' yet nothing else works.
- I don't find a way to change the contrast of the LCD (no potentiometer or whatsoever)

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

import smbus2 as smbus
import time

# Define some device parameters
I2C_ADDR = 0x3e     # I2C device address, if any error, change this address to 0x3f
LCD_WIDTH = 16      # Maximum characters per line

# Define some device constants
LCD_CHR = 1     # Mode - Sending data
LCD_CMD = 0     # Mode - Sending command

LCD_LINE_1 = 0x80   # LCD RAM address for the 1st line
LCD_LINE_2 = 0xC0   # LCD RAM address for the 2nd line
LCD_LINE_3 = 0x94   # LCD RAM address for the 3rd line
LCD_LINE_4 = 0xD4   # LCD RAM address for the 4th line

LCD_BACKLIGHT = 0x08  # On

ENABLE = 0b00000100     # Enable bit

# Timing constants
E_PULSE = 0.0005
E_DELAY = 0.0005

# Open I2C interface
# bus = smbus.SMBus(0)  # Rev 1 Pi uses 0
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)    # Rev 2 Pi uses 1


def lcd_init():
    # Initialise display
    lcd_byte(0x33, LCD_CMD)     # 110011 Initialise
    lcd_byte(0x32, LCD_CMD)     # 110010 Initialise
    lcd_byte(0x06, LCD_CMD)     # 000110 Cursor move direction
    lcd_byte(0x0C, LCD_CMD)     # 001100 Display On,Cursor Off, Blink Off
    lcd_byte(0x28, LCD_CMD)     # 101000 Data length, number of lines, font size
    lcd_byte(0x01, LCD_CMD)     # 000001 Clear display
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)


def lcd_byte(bits, mode):
    # Send byte to data pins
    # bits = the data
    # mode = 1 for data
    #        0 for command

    bits_high = mode | (bits & 0xF0) | LCD_BACKLIGHT
    bits_low = mode | ((bits << 4) & 0xF0) | LCD_BACKLIGHT

    # High bits
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, bits_high)
    lcd_toggle_enable(bits_high)

    # Low bits
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, bits_low)
    lcd_toggle_enable(bits_low)


def lcd_toggle_enable(bits):
    # Toggle enable
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, (bits | ENABLE))
    time.sleep(E_PULSE)
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDR, (bits & ~ENABLE))
    time.sleep(E_DELAY)


def lcd_string(message, line):
    # Send string to display
    message = message.ljust(LCD_WIDTH, " ")

    lcd_byte(line, LCD_CMD)

    for i in range(LCD_WIDTH):
        lcd_byte(ord(message[i]), LCD_CHR)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lcd_init()

    while True:
        # Send some test
        lcd_string("Hello      ", LCD_LINE_1)
        lcd_string("      World", LCD_LINE_2)
        print('LCD printing!')
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Welcome to the club. I have few of them and none works for me. I spent really a lot of time to make some progress and only recently I started suspecting the few things (after proper value of pull up resistors), i.e.: **a)** length of the cables to the board (highly recommend to reduce as much as possible, avoid interference with other wires and make sure nothing else is on the same bus), **b)** power supply and current (must be 5v and that's what make me wondering if I need to solder separate, thick enough, cables to it). Note, I even checked signal with oscilloscope, no good picture came out.

Comment: Some useful links: https://forum.dexterindustries.com/t/solved-grove-lcd-rgb-backlight-unknown-i2c-addresses/2879, https://os.mbed.com/users/cmatz3/notebook/grove-rgb-lcd-display/, etc.